# how to get image name , size , temp from image path/link?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

When i use file upload i can get like this.

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

But i want to know , how to get image name , size , temp from image path/link

```
www.example.com/img/test.png
```

Using php ?

Thank you for all

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? didn't understand what you want

Comment: @bansi Im thinking he means how he get filename, size, temp from direct access of the URL. but all just a guess

Comment: yes - Andrew, thank you^^

Comment: name you already know, size [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), `temp` <-- don't know what you mean. If you want full image details you can use [Imagick::getImageProperties](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageproperties.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $filename='img/1967-jaguar.jpg';//image path
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
    //print_r($path_parts);
    echo 'Dir Name: '.$path_parts['dirname'].'<br>';
    echo 'Base Name: '.$path_parts['basename'].'<br>';;
    echo 'Extension: '.$path_parts['extension'].'<br>';;
    echo 'File Name: '.$path_parts['filename'].'<br>';;
    echo $file_size=filesize($filename);
    echo 'File Size: '.$file_size.'kb';
    //for image width height and mime
    $imagesize=getimagesize($filename);
    print_r($imagesize);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

Regarding `pathinfo()`, from php manual:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/img/image.jpg');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

You can also play with [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: i think the OP wants to get info of remote image.

Comment: Maybe. He will tell us .. or he won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use....

";
Echo $path['basename']."
";
Echo $path['extension']."
";

?>

Try it's working fine...